# How to look up an NHibernate entity's table mapping from the type of the entity?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Once I've mapped my domain in NHibernate, how can I reverse lookup those mappings somewhere else in my code?

Example:

The entity `Pony` is mapped to a table named "AAZF1203" for some reason. (Stupid legacy database table names!) I want to find out that table name from the NH mappings using only the `typeof(Pony)` because I have to write a query elsewhere.

### How can I make the following test pass?

```
private const string LegacyPonyTableName = "AAZF1203";

[Test]
public void MakeSureThatThePonyEntityIsMappedToCorrectTable()
{
    string ponyTable = GetNHibernateTableMappingFor(typeof(Pony));
    Assert.AreEqual(LegacyPonyTableName, ponyTable);
}
```

In other words, what does the `GetNHibernateTableMappingFor(Type t)` need to look like?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At which point do you need that information?

Because it depends on what you have...

Not long ago I had to get the table name from an audit event listener, and I used this:

```
IPostDatabaseOperationEventArgs args //parameter
var tableName = ((ILockable)args.Persister).RootTableName.ToLower();
```

You could also get it from the session...

```
((ILockable)session.GetSessionImplementation()
                   .GetEntityPersister(null, new Pony())).RootTableName
```

Comment: Beautiful! I used the first operation you mentioned because I am trying to pull this out in a SaveEventListener. I can pull the persister from the eventArgs there. I didn't realize that I had to cast it to ILockable. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

I have found this to work to get the name of the table where the entities are persisted.

1. You have to have an instance of `NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration`
2. You request an instance of `NHibernate.Mapping.Table` for the given persistent type.
3. The `Name` property of the `Table` instance corresponds to the name of the the table where the entities are persisted.

See the code below.

```
NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration config = new Configuration();
/*
The initialisation here like config.AddAssembly(... and so forth
*/
NHibernate.Mapping.Table table = config.GetClassMapping(typeof(T)).RootTable;
String NameOfTableOfInterest = table.Name;
```

This could be wrapped in a function like so

```
public static String GetTableName<T>(NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration config)
{
    return config.GetClassMapping(typeof(T)).RootTable.Name;
}
```

**NOTE:** Strange enough, the properties `Catalog` and `Schema of the`NHibernate.Mapping.Table` have no value. At least, not in my case.

Comment: NHibernate stuff seem to all have old answers, at least for me. Anyway, this won't work if you have mapped an entity via entity-name, because GetClassMapping internally performs a dictionary look up. When mapping via class only, the said dictionary contains the full name of the type. But when mapping via entity-name, the dictionary contains the said entity name.